# How to Parse string to json object with regex

Tags: javascript, json

I have as string like this, I want parse this string to Json
object, how can I do it. Hope some one can help me with javascript!

"{1470272514:[],1470279616:[[D,SZ100917],[D,SZ108117],[D,SZ108118],[D,SZ109099],[D,SZ112122],[D,SZ117002],[D,SZ118119],[D,SZ118121],[D,SZ118122],[D,SZ118250],[D,SZ118253],[D,SZ300527],[D,SZ360018],[D,SZ360627],[D,SZ360788],[D,SZ360863],[D,SZ360930],[D,SZ362146],[D,SZ362188],[D,SZ362199],[D,SZ362279],[D,SZ362355],[D,SZ362460],[D,SZ362524],[D,SZ365010],[D,SZ365057],[D,SZ365096],[D,SZ365208],[D,SZ365407],[D,SZ000602],[D,SZ000787],[D,SZ000033],[D,SZ000527],[D,SZ000594],[D,SZ200770],[D,SZ000658],[D,SZ000155],[D,SZ000522],[D,SZ000569],[D,SZ000765],[D,SZ000832],[D,SZ000015],[D,SZ000549],[D,SZ000660],[D,SZ000675],[D,SZ000556],[D,SZ000618],[D,SZ000024],[D,SZ000689],[D,SZ000805],[D,SZ000003],[D,SZ000047],[D,SZ000583],[D,SZ000827],[D,SZ000562],[D,SZ000578],[D,SZ000515],[D,SZ002257],[D,SZ002525],[D,SZ002720],[D,SZ200002],[D,SZ200003],[D,SZ200015],[D,SZ200024],[D,SZ200039],[D,SZ200513],[D,SZ002710],[D,SZ200041],[D,SZ300060],[D,SZ300186],[D,SZ300361],[D,SZ300528],[D,SZ360034],[D,SZ360600],[D,SZ360750],[D,SZ360861],[D,SZ360950],[D,SZ360957],[D,SZ362023],[D,SZ362369],[D,SZ362436],[D,SZ362465],[D,SZ362663],[D,SZ362681],[D,SZ365109],[D,SZ365215],[D,SZ365316],[D,SZ365411],[D,SZ365515],[D,SZ000653],[D,SZ000013],[D,SZ000730],[D,SZ000621],[D,SZ000412],[D,SZ000542],[D,SZ000991],[D,SZ000405],[D,SZ000535],[D,SZ200057],[D,SZ000769],[D,SZ000817],[D,SZ000763],[D,SZ200013],[D,SZ000406],[D,SZ000699],[D,SZ000866],[D,SZ000956],[D,SZ300531],[D,SZ360030],[D,SZ360566],[D,SZ360608],[D,SZ360609],[D,SZ362109],[D,SZ362168],[D,SZ362285],[D,SZ362301],[D,SZ362379],[D,SZ362386],[D,SZ362452],[D,SZ362729],[D,SZ362763],[D,SZ365125],[D,SZ365266],[D,SZ365518],[D,SZ101650],[D,SZ169105],[D,SZ360413],[D,SZ360546],[D,SZ360728],[D,SZ360803],[D,SZ360818],[D,SZ361696],[D,SZ362101],[D,SZ362116],[D,SZ362208],[D,SZ362261],[D,SZ362351],[D,SZ362438],[D,SZ362455],[D,SZ362657],[D,SZ362723],[D,SZ362802],[D,SZ365036],[D,SZ365187],[D,SZ365219],[D,SZ365234],[D,SZ365373],[D,SZ365449],[D,SZ072325],[D,SZ082325],[D,SZ300530],[D,SZ360048],[D,SZ360068],[D,SZ360681],[D,SZ360988],[D,SZ362009],[D,SZ362011],[D,SZ362044],[D,SZ362064],[D,SZ362221],[D,SZ362506],[D,SZ362562],[D,SZ362696],[D,SZ362717],[D,SZ362746],[D,SZ365016],[D,SZ365091],[D,SZ365115],[D,SZ365153],[D,SZ365344],[D,SZ365360],[D,SZ365364],[D,SZ365389],[D,SZ365441],[D,SZ300535],[D,SZ360533],[D,SZ360667],[D,SZ360671],[D,SZ360792],[D,SZ360909],[D,SZ360928],[D,SZ360997],[D,SZ362092],[D,SZ362228],[D,SZ362286],[D,SZ362570],[D,SZ362624],[D,SZ365019],[D,SZ365088],[D,SZ365134],[D,SZ365374],[D,SZ365440],[D,SZ365493],[D,SZ360514],[D,SZ360625],[D,SZ360890],[D,SZ362269],[D,SZ362310],[D,SZ362614],[D,SZ002808],[D,SZ360010],[D,SZ360526],[D,SZ360536],[D,SZ362065],[D,SZ362175],[D,SZ362268],[D,SZ362314],[D,SZ362585],[D,SZ362706],[D,SZ365178],[D,SZ365222],[D,SZ365292],[D,SZ365418],[D,SZ365438]]}"

Comment: JSON.parse(myString) isn't good enough?Ah, I see...the strings aren't quoted.

Comment: I can't use JSON.parse to parse this string, I want try to use RegExp to translate, but I am poor with regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This site is great: https://regex101.com/#javascript

There's probably a fancier RegEx to do everything in one shot, but I'm too lazy to explore it, so here you go.

```js
var mess = "{1470272514:[],1470279616:[[D,SZ100917],[D,SZ108117],[D,SZ108118],[D,SZ109099],[D,SZ112122],[D,SZ117002],[D,SZ118119],[D,SZ118121],[D,SZ118122],[D,SZ118250],[D,SZ118253],[D,SZ300527],[D,SZ360018],[D,SZ360627],[D,SZ360788],[D,SZ360863],[D,SZ360930],[D,SZ362146],[D,SZ362188],[D,SZ362199],[D,SZ362279],[D,SZ362355],[D,SZ362460],[D,SZ362524],[D,SZ365010],[D,SZ365057],[D,SZ365096],[D,SZ365208],[D,SZ365407],[D,SZ000602],[D,SZ000787],[D,SZ000033],[D,SZ000527],[D,SZ000594],[D,SZ200770],[D,SZ000658],[D,SZ000155],[D,SZ000522],[D,SZ000569],[D,SZ000765],[D,SZ000832],[D,SZ000015],[D,SZ000549],[D,SZ000660],[D,SZ000675],[D,SZ000556],[D,SZ000618],[D,SZ000024],[D,SZ000689],[D,SZ000805],[D,SZ000003],[D,SZ000047],[D,SZ000583],[D,SZ000827],[D,SZ000562],[D,SZ000578],[D,SZ000515],[D,SZ002257],[D,SZ002525],[D,SZ002720],[D,SZ200002],[D,SZ200003],[D,SZ200015],[D,SZ200024],[D,SZ200039],[D,SZ200513],[D,SZ002710],[D,SZ200041],[D,SZ300060],[D,SZ300186],[D,SZ300361],[D,SZ300528],[D,SZ360034],[D,SZ360600],[D,SZ360750],[D,SZ360861],[D,SZ360950],[D,SZ360957],[D,SZ362023],[D,SZ362369],[D,SZ362436],[D,SZ362465],[D,SZ362663],[D,SZ362681],[D,SZ365109],[D,SZ365215],[D,SZ365316],[D,SZ365411],[D,SZ365515],[D,SZ000653],[D,SZ000013],[D,SZ000730],[D,SZ000621],[D,SZ000412],[D,SZ000542],[D,SZ000991],[D,SZ000405],[D,SZ000535],[D,SZ200057],[D,SZ000769],[D,SZ000817],[D,SZ000763],[D,SZ200013],[D,SZ000406],[D,SZ000699],[D,SZ000866],[D,SZ000956],[D,SZ300531],[D,SZ360030],[D,SZ360566],[D,SZ360608],[D,SZ360609],[D,SZ362109],[D,SZ362168],[D,SZ362285],[D,SZ362301],[D,SZ362379],[D,SZ362386],[D,SZ362452],[D,SZ362729],[D,SZ362763],[D,SZ365125],[D,SZ365266],[D,SZ365518],[D,SZ101650],[D,SZ169105],[D,SZ360413],[D,SZ360546],[D,SZ360728],[D,SZ360803],[D,SZ360818],[D,SZ361696],[D,SZ362101],[D,SZ362116],[D,SZ362208],[D,SZ362261],[D,SZ362351],[D,SZ362438],[D,SZ362455],[D,SZ362657],[D,SZ362723],[D,SZ362802],[D,SZ365036],[D,SZ365187],[D,SZ365219],[D,SZ365234],[D,SZ365373],[D,SZ365449],[D,SZ072325],[D,SZ082325],[D,SZ300530],[D,SZ360048],[D,SZ360068],[D,SZ360681],[D,SZ360988],[D,SZ362009],[D,SZ362011],[D,SZ362044],[D,SZ362064],[D,SZ362221],[D,SZ362506],[D,SZ362562],[D,SZ362696],[D,SZ362717],[D,SZ362746],[D,SZ365016],[D,SZ365091],[D,SZ365115],[D,SZ365153],[D,SZ365344],[D,SZ365360],[D,SZ365364],[D,SZ365389],[D,SZ365441],[D,SZ300535],[D,SZ360533],[D,SZ360667],[D,SZ360671],[D,SZ360792],[D,SZ360909],[D,SZ360928],[D,SZ360997],[D,SZ362092],[D,SZ362228],[D,SZ362286],[D,SZ362570],[D,SZ362624],[D,SZ365019],[D,SZ365088],[D,SZ365134],[D,SZ365374],[D,SZ365440],[D,SZ365493],[D,SZ360514],[D,SZ360625],[D,SZ360890],[D,SZ362269],[D,SZ362310],[D,SZ362614],[D,SZ002808],[D,SZ360010],[D,SZ360526],[D,SZ360536],[D,SZ362065],[D,SZ362175],[D,SZ362268],[D,SZ362314],[D,SZ362585],[D,SZ362706],[D,SZ365178],[D,SZ365222],[D,SZ365292],[D,SZ365418],[D,SZ365438]]}";

var cleaner = mess.replace(/(D),(SZ\d*)/g, '"$1","$2"');
var clean = cleaner.replace(/(\d*):/g, '"$1":');
var o = JSON.parse(clean);
console.dir(o);
```